# Browser Certificate Validation

Tags: google-chrome, certificate

I have an Internal Certificate not signed by CA. I had previously chosen to forcefully trust this certificate on my Chrome browser. Let's say if it expires and some later point... Will chrome check for certificate validity like Expiry etc., if I had previously chosen to forcefully trust the certificate?

Answer (score 1):

Unless Chrome was started with the "--ignore-certificate-errors" argument, Chrome will complain about any expired certificate in the chain even if they are  imported to a trusted store (such as Trusted Root Certification Authorities). In order to mitigate this, you may (re)generate the certificate with an extended expiry date.